# Getting status from Modelsim

Tags: command-line, tcl, modelsim

I am running Modelsim by command line:

```
catch { exec vsim -c -do run.do } rcode
```

1. Some simulations are taking pretty long. How can I get status information, i.e. every 10 minutes?
2. I have seen many examples like:

   ```
   vsim -c test_bench -do "run -all"
   ```

   I suppose all necessary files need to be compiled before this command, like

   ```
   vcom -quiet -93 -work work name.vhd
   vcom -quiet -93 -work work name2.vhd
   ...
   vsim -c test_bench -do "run -all"
   ```

   Is this correct?

Comment: It's better to ask two separate questions rather than one with two not-very-closely-related subquestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get information out of a subprocess, you usually get the subprocess to write to its standard output channel from time to time. You can then read from that (via a pipeline).

```
set pipe [open |[list exec vsim -c -do run.do]]
while {[gets $pipe line] >= 0} {
    puts "I've just read '$line' from vsim"
}
catch { close $pipe } rcode
```

As long as the program does actually write lines out from time to time, you'll receive them (modulo OS and subprocess library buffering) when they arrive. The above code is *synchronous;* we have asynchronous versions too (allowing your code to do things other than waiting for the subprocess at the same time, such as running a GUI) but the code for them is usually a bit longer.

Comment: For your second question, it ought to be obvious; if it doesn't work if you don't do it, you need to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I already tried it. Unfortunately, I get the following error:  

           `expected integer but got "Reading D:/ModelSim/ModelSim_10.3c/tcl/vsim/pref.t" while executing
"open |list eval [ exec vsim -c -do run.do ]"`